# splitsh / lite: Error when build on Windows 10

Tags: go, mingw-w64

https://github.com/splitsh/lite/issues/58

Hello,

I am trying to install splitsh-lite in windows 10. I read #18 and followed the manual instructions until the last step when an error is thrown:

In cmd:

go get github.com/splitsh/lite

github.com/libgit2/git2go
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgit2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In MINGW64:
$ go build -o splitsh-lite github.com/splitsh/lite

github.com/libgit2/git2go
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgit2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Could you help me or give me some guidelines in order to build splitsh-lite?

Thank you!

Comment: What is "#18"? Did you install libgit2 as the instructions say and put it into a path where your mingw ld can find it?

Comment: @Adrian #18 means issue ·18 of link mentioned above: https://github.com/splitsh/lite/issues/18 Yes, I followed all the instructions and libgit2 works fine, but not when I tried to build splitsh. Anyway, the Sven's aswer works for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had issues on Windows, too, I used the Windows Linux Subsystem. There is no need to get that running in the native Windows command line anymore.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

### Install GO

```
wget -q https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
  tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.12.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

### Install splitsh

```
 wget -q https://github.com/splitsh/lite/releases/download/v1.0.1/lite_linux_amd64.tar.gz
  tar -zxpf lite_linux_amd64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local/bin/
  cp /usr/local/bin/splitsh-lite "$(git --exec-path)"/git-splitsh
```

The release versions in my commands might be outdated, I did this in November 2019. Please replace them if needed. Then you're ready to perform your repository modifications with splitsh.